How to create a modern Site Page in a Document Library (not within SitePages)
I'm trying to make a Document Library able to display modern Site Pages within that library, but it doesn't work. When attempting to open the page, it appears completely blank.
If I place the same page inside /SitePages/, it works fine. Is there a way to resolve this, or does it indeed not work in other libraries?

"Creation of modern pages is supported in the Site Pages library only. Additionally, you cannot change the URL of a page."
Create and use modern pages on a SharePoint site
